# Where are the HiDPI scaling settings in 18.04.1?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, hdpi

Just installed 18.04.1 on a fresh VM and no longer see any settings to set the global display scaling to 2x on a HiDPI display.

I saw a thread where someone suggested using dconf to set org.gnome.desktop.interface.scaling-factor to 2 manually, but it's still displaying at 1x despite that.

Answer (score 0):

The scaling setting on Ubuntu 18.04 can be found in the Settings tool: Devices - Displays. You will see the "Scale" setting, allowing to select an integer for global scaling of the display:

[image]

In addition to changing the Scale setting, you may also try playing around with font scaling. This is found [in Gnome Tweak, Fonts](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035521/349837). You can provide a fractional font scaling factor there. You can experiment with both settings to find the combination that suits you best.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my Displays section of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (running in VirtualBox) there is no Scale option. Just Orientation, Resolution and a little bit below Night Light.

Comment: The settings are for hihg-resolution displays. Check the resolution you provided in your VM.