# How to increase the global text size on a high DPI monitor?

Tags: fonts, text

I'm running a 4k monitor and all the text on web browsers and UI items looks really small. Is there any way that I can increase the text withoug having to use the `ctrl +` option?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1035520/832813

Answer (score 2):

In "Settings", "Display" tab, you can change the **scale factor**. This factor scales your overall desktop. The scale factor is, unfortunately, only available in integer numbers such as 1x (100%) or 2x (200%). Fractional scaling, where you can customize the overall  scaling granularity, is now in an experimental stage, and will hopefully be available soon. Still, you can [enable fractional scaling](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04) if you wish, but it may not perform well.

Next to adjusting the overall scaling, you can also adjust only the **font scaling**. This setting is not exposed to the user by default. For the setting to be available, install Gnome Tweaks using the Software center. On the "Fonts" tab of the tool, you can define a scaling factor.

Look for a combination of Scale and Font Scale that works best for you.

With respect to **websites**, you can have Firefox show websites somewhat enlarged by default. This feature has become available only very recently, with Firefox 73. In the "Preferences" under "Zoom", you can change the default zoom factor to something larger (or smaller).