# Unable to change screen resolution after update

Tags: display, display-resolution

As detailed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499596/black-screen-on-log-in-after-update/1499599#1499599) following a recent update I am now unable to alter the screen resolution to anything other than 1920 x 1080. This appears to have been the reason why initially when logging in I got nothing but a blank screen and my original question revolved around that. However the real problem seems to be that any setting other than 1920 x 1080 simply does not work (and I had previously had 1280 x 720 as my default setting that Ubuntu was trying to log in with). As my real problem seems to be changing the screen resolution, I thought I'd open a new question.

- **OS Name:** Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- **Hardware Model:** Lenovo ThinkPad E15 Gen 3
- **Graphics:** RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.54, 6.5.0-14-generic)

Until a recent update I was happily using Ubuntu with a screen resolution of 1280 x 720. Now if I go to Settings > Screen Display and attempt to select any other option than 1920 x 1080 the screen goes black for 20 seconds after pressing apply and then comes back firmly on 1920 x 1080.

Attempting `xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1280x720` in the terminal gives:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
```

If I try an older version of 22.04 which I installed from 1280 x 720 works absolutely fine, just as it has done for nearly 2 years.

I would greatly appreciate any help in changing the resolution back to 1280 x 720 and 1920 x 1080 is almost illegibly tiny on my small laptop screen.

Comment: Xrandr probably won't work with wayland. If you sign in using an x session instead of wayland do things work properly?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Good question. I did try using the cog icon on the login screen to login with Ubuntu on Xorg and unfortunately this made no difference

Answer (score 1):

I use 1920 x 1080 and seeing the font and objects is a struggle. A alternative option that might work for you is to increase the size of the fonts and objects. It takes several tweaks, but here is one you can start with if you choose to go this route.
[Global font](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212320/how-to-increase-the-global-text-size-on-a-high-dpi-monitor) and [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035520/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-for-a-hdpi-4k-display)

(edit the toolbar in KDE to make the icons larger) (Firefox for example in about:config .. layout.css.devPixelsPerPx)
(LibreOffice in Tools, Options, View, you can select large icons - GIMP also)
(I also select a large mouse pointer and so on) I don't know your particular uses, but with everything I work with there is a tweak to increase the size. *be careful with how big you increase the size, baby step it.