# How do I increase the font size in Ubuntu 20.10 only for one 4K display?

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution

I can change the font by many way

[How do I increase the font size in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for a HDPI / 4K display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035520/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-for-a-hdpi-4k-display)

but all that settings are for all screen

Is it possible to increase font only for one screen ? My 2 others screen in 1080p doesn't need to have bigger fonts.

Comment: I am afraid this is one of the limitations of the multimonitor support in Gnome. You cannot have different scaling per display afaik. I am not sure if you can set a different scaling factor for each monitor: that could help to some extent